# My UPS inverter is making treble noise

Tags: battery-charging, inverter, ups, buzzing

My home UPS is making noise mainly 19.5 kHz as shown in image while charging. It’s 7 years old now.
Model is Sukam Falcon 800

Q. How to solve this issue? [image: frequency in 6500 Hz steps]

Comment: note that increments of 6500Hz in increasing volume

Comment: 6 kHz is a typical corner frequency for many SMPSes. Best guess is that you have one or more bad capacitors in your UPS, possibly some auxiliary power supply, with too low capacitance to make the regulation loop stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mental Fourier Analysis thinks you have a switching regulator at 19.5 kHz with 50 Hz sidebands with harmonics of 50 and subharmonics of 19.5kHz.

This tells me the high voltage DC voltage has ripple that causes the magnetic ferrite to make noise like a piezoelectric which it can't help if the dielectric bulk capacitors are not damping the voltage.

The most common indicator are slightly bulged cap gas relief vents on top of the large cylindrical parts.

[image][*](https://circuitspedia.com/sukam-digital-inverter-circuit-diagram/)

Comment: thanks alot. i changed my battery to good one and noise went down by a lot that its no longer audible after short acclimatization. Its my old ups with my old battery (already <12V)